# Conditional Text Shopify Cart

Tags: shopify

I want to show item based custom text in shopify cart page, please help me. Currently I've two different type of products but both of them showing the same informational text on cart.liquid and I want the text to be different based upon the product added to cart.

Comment: you can use the cart line item properties

Comment: Can you explain to me, how?

Comment: you want to show the same product in the cart but with distinct text to differentiate them when you add again with different text?

Answer (score 0):

you want to show the same product in the cart but with distinct text to differentiate them when add others

in your shopify product page add this line in the form:

```
<input type="text" id="additional" name="properties[additional]" value="" />
```

then at the front end add different texts to the same product, adding to cart.

In the cart, to show the text you have to add the code:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}

<!--YOUR CODE HTML-->

    {% for p in item.properties %}
        {% if p.first == 'additional' %}
         <div>{{ p.last }}</div>
        {% endif %}     
    {% endfor %}

<!--YOUR CODE HTML-->

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can have a data-binding expression,

```
/Productinfo.aspx?ProductInformation=<%#Eval(productinfo)%>
```

Or in the most simplest way is

```
eval("productInfo" + PID + " = val[PId]");
```

Hope this will give you a starting point. :)

Comment: Shopify is not Microsoft stuff at all!